# Does xargs -P run background processes? How is it different from using an &?

Tags: shell-script, xargs, background-process

I have a file `processes.txt` as follows:

```
process_1.sh
process_2.sh
process_3.sh
```

I will run the following on the terminal:

```
cat processes.txt | xargs -L1 -P3 sh
```

How would this be different if I had a script `executable_processes.sh` as follows:

```
process_1 &
process_2 &
process_3 &
wait
```

where `process_1`, `process_2` and `process_3` are scripts with execute permissions but performing the same tasks as `process_1.sh`, `process_2.sh` and `process_3.sh`, and I ran the following on the terminal:

```
sh executable_processes.sh
```

My colleague told me that the first example (using `xargs -L1 -P3`) runs the three processes "truly in parallel", while the second example (`sh executable_processes.sh`) that uses `&` runs the three processes as background processes but still sends them to the background consecutively, i.e. `process_1` is sent to the background first, next `process_2` is sent to the background and then `process_3` is sent to the background. Therefore he prefers that I use the first example. But my problem with the first approach is that I do not know how to use `xargs -L1 -P3` if the three lines in `processes.txt` were as follows:

```
cat input_1.txt | process_1
cat input_2.txt | process_2
cat input_3.txt | process_3
```

Let's say I modified the file `processes.txt` as follows:

```
input_1.txt | process_1
input_2.txt | process_2
input_3.txt | process_3
```

And then run

```
cat processes.txt | xargs -L1 -P3 cat
```

This throws the error

```
cat: '|': No such file or directory
```

I want to be able to run `cat input_1.txt` first and the pipe the output to `process_1` and so on. But `input_1.txt`, `|` and `process_1` are being handled as arguments to `cat`

If using `&` and `xargs -P` are not different from each other would it be more reasonable to simply run a script that contains:

```
cat input_1.txt | process_1 &
cat input_2.txt | process_2 &
cat input_3.txt | process_3 &
```

Answer (score 0):

Background processes run by the shell all run in parallel; you can verify this by running

```
sleep 10 & sleep 10 & sleep 10 & wait
```

You’ll wait for ten seconds (or just a little more), not thirty.

So

```
process_1 < input_1.txt &
process_2 < input_2.txt &
process_3 < input_3.txt &
```

or

```
for i in {1..3}; do "process_$i" < "input_$i.txt" & done
```

will start all three processes, with three different inputs, in parallel.

If you wanted to do something similar with `xargs`, you could use `-I`:

```
printf "%s\n" {1..3} | xargs -I{} -P3 sh -c "process_{} < input_{}.txt"
```

Comment: To more specifically address your colleague's assertion that `xargs -P` does things "truly in parallel"- even modern CPUs do literally _nothing_ in _actual_ simultaneity.  While there is an extremely small difference between `command & command & command &` and `xargs -P sh 'command'`, `xargs` will _still_ at the end of the day be sending one instance of `command` at a time into the background to be executed.

Comment: I ultimately used the approach with `cat processes.txt | xargs -L1 -P3 sh -c` with every line of `processes.txt` within quotes. I have been asked to keep this approach instead of using `&` at the end of each line.

Comment: @DopeGhoti "_modern CPUs do literally nothing in actual simultaneity_" - I'm heading off-topic here but are you really saying that a four core CPU doesn't execute four (compute-bound) processes simultaneously?

Comment: Dig deep enough and things are indeed sequential.  A four-core processor can execute four instructions per _clock cycle_ but within that cycle the instructions are in series.

Comment: @DopeGhoti no, a four-core processor executes instructions in parallel, there’s nothing sequential (apart from, perhaps, serialisation with some accesses to the shared cache). Even within a single core some instructions can run in parallel (across different execution units).